# Get the other field value in case of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE itemmast (
  cid INTEGER,
  description varchar(30),
  defaultprice DOUBLE);

INSERT INTO itemmast VALUES (1, 'Item 1', '0');
INSERT INTO itemmast VALUES (2, 'Item 2', '8');
INSERT INTO itemmast VALUES (3, 'Item 3', '5.5');
INSERT INTO itemmast VALUES (4, 'Item 4', '0');
INSERT INTO itemmast VALUES (5, 'Item 5', '59');


CREATE TABLE specialprice (
  cid INTEGER,
  username varchar(30),
  newprice DOUBLE);

INSERT INTO specialprice VALUES (4, 'UserS', '10');
INSERT INTO specialprice VALUES (2, 'UserX', '115');
```

I want to get the value of [newprice] for specific user just in case its in the [specialprice] table, otherwise get the [defaultprice] from the [itemmast] table

So far I have this but not working as expected.

```
SELECT itemmast.*,newprice,
CASE specialprice.newprice
    WHEN NULL
      THEN itemmast.defaultprice
ELSE
  specialprice.newprice
END AS itemprice
FROM itemmast
LEFT JOIN specialprice ON specialprice.cid = itemmast.cid
where itemmast.cid = '1' and username= 'UserS'
```

Comment: "*but not working as expected*" is not a valid error message. Please tell us what is "not working"

Comment: @John Woo. Read my post I said "I want to get the value of [newprice] for specific user just in case its in the [specialprice] table, otherwise get the [defaultprice] from the [itemmast] table"

Answer (score 2):

Change your `CASE` statement into

```
CASE WHEN specialprice.cid IS NULL
     THEN itemmast.defaultprice
     ELSE specialprice.newprice
END as RealPrice
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa03c/3)

Or alternatively use `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(specialprice.newprice, itemmast.defaultprice)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa03c/6)

Comment: If the cid and / or username dont exist in specialprice table, the record should still be retrieve from itemmast but using the defaultprice as RealPrice, in your solution it will not return the record from itemmast http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5db1/10

Comment: @PaulSanchez because in your `where` clause you are using `AND` try changin it to `OR`

Comment: @PaulSanchez `WHERE itemmast.cid = '1' OR username= 'UserS'`

Comment: Cant use OR it should only return 1 record NOT username OR cid

Comment: @PaulSanchez so what record it will return? i think it makes no sense of using `where` condition if it still return one record even if it doesn't saitisfies your condition

Comment: If I enter WHERE cid = 1 AND username = 'UserY' it should return [1, 'Item 1', 3] because cid1 /UserY Not found in table specialprice. If I enter cid=1 AND username = userS still it will return [1, 'Item 1', 3] because cid=1 NOT found in table specialprice

Answer (score 0):

Why not rather us [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

> •IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
>
> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the
>   context in which it is used.

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(1,0);
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(NULL,10);
        -> 10
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(1/0,10);
        -> 10
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(1/0,'yes');
        -> 'yes'
```

So in your example, something like

```
SELECT  itemmast.*,
        newprice,  
        IFNULL(specialprice.newprice, itemmast.defaultprice) itemprice
FROM    itemmast  LEFT JOIN 
        specialprice ON specialprice.cid = itemmast.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic approach, use IF(,,):

```
IF (specialprice.newprice IS NULL, specialprice.defaultprice, specialprice.newprice)
```

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are OK, but the *reason* your SQL is not working is that `null` is never equal to anything, not even `null`, and your case statement is comparing the value of `specialprice.newprice` with `null` which will *never* be true.

The only test that is true for null is the special `is null` test, so you must use that:

```
case when specialprice.newprice is null ... else ... end
```

or use a built-in funciton:

```
select ifnull(specialprice.newprice, itemmast.defaultprice) ...
```